# How to get response along with setting up cookie with Request::create( ) method in laravel?

Tags: laravel

**This is my api.php where i have defined two routes:**

```
Route::get('/test', function (Request $request) {
   
    return response()->json([
        "msg" => "testing"
    ])->withCookie(cookie('hey', 'hello cookie'));
});


Route::get('/token', function () {
    $request = Request::create('/api/test', 'get');
    $decode = json_decode(app()->handle($request)->getContent());
    return response()->json($decode);
});
```

Comming to the point,what i want to achieve is when i request for `http:://localhost/api/token`, i want to create a request for another route that is `http:://localhost/api/test` and and i want to get response from it along with by creating cookie as defined in function itself.I only able to get response data from above code which i have written but unable to get see cookie created !!
So there any ways to achieve it ?

Comment: can't you do all the logic in a single function?  so you can call that function when route call

Comment: yeah but but i have such scenario that can't do in single function

Answer (score 0):

To send an HTTP request from within your application, you need to use the HTTP client which is present in Laravel itself.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client